# Selecting multiple draggable items on the fly in jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to use jQueryUI's Draggable feature to grab not only the selected element and drag it around, but also all the siblings that follow the selected element.

Example: I have a table with the hours of the day across the top, and a list of employees down the side. Each employee is responsible for giving care to certain patients. But if one employee, let's say April, is called away at say 1pm, I need to be able to grab their first appointment that they will miss and just drag it and all following appointments down to Bridget's row. If April comes back, I can grab the appointments from Bridget starting at 2pm, and drag them back to April's appointment book.

Using the default jQueryUI, I would have to drag each of the 15-minute appointments individually. I've looked at some of the multi-draggable implementations, but all seem to be dependent on the user selecting multiple items before the event fires. I was wanting to be able to fire the event, then have the "start" or some method automatically select the siblings after the chosen element.

Is this possible?

Comment: share some code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It could be possible with selectable and draggable. Please edit your post and include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had some time, here is a basic example of one way you could do this.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wmjt1v7s/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">Times</div>
  <ol id="select-times" class="ui-widget-content">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">01:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">02:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">03:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">04:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">05:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">06:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">07:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">08:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">09:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">10:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">11:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">12:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">13:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">14:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">15:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">16:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">17:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">18:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">19:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">20:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">21:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">22:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">23:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">24:00</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="ui-widget-header">Schedules</div>
  <ol id="schedules" class="ui-widget-content">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <label>April</label>
      <div class="drop-times">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <label>Linda</label>
      <div class="drop-times">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <label>Barry</label>
      <div class="drop-times">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <label>Ellen</label>
      <div class="drop-times">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#select-times .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#select-times .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#select-times {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.group-times {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 2px;
}

#schedules {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#schedules label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-left: 4px;
  width: 56px;
}

#schedules .drop-times {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  width: 75%;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#select-times li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var selected = [];
  $("#select-times > li").draggable({
    helper: function() {
      var $group = $("<div>", {
        class: "group-times"
      });
      if (selected.length) {
        $group.html(selected.join(", "));
        console.log("Helper: ", $group);
      } else {
        $group.html($(this).text());
      }
      return $group;
    }
  });
  $("#select-times").selectable({
    selected: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.selected).each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).text());
      });
    }
  });
  $(".drop-times").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).html($(ui.helper).text());
      $(ui.helper).remove();
      $(".ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
    }
  });
});
```

Basically, each list item is draggable. We make a helper that contains the time of the one dragged item or the selected items. This is then dragged into a slot in the schedule.